# C# Winform runtime load Windows Forms Controller Library

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, runtime

I wanted to load a dll file runtime what contains Windows Forms Controller Library in C# Winform app.
I need help.

Thanks for help:
Horbert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code

```
using System.Reflection;

Assembly dll= Assembly.Load("DALL"); //DALL name of your assembly
Type MyLoadClass = dll.GetType("DALL.LoadClass"); // name of your class
 object  obj = Activator.CreateInstance(MyLoadClass)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string assemblyPath = @"D:/MyAssembly.dll";
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
```

or using Reflection.

```
string assemblyPath = @"D:/MyAssembly.dll";
Assembly MyDll = Assembly.Load(assemblyPath);
Type MyLoadClass = MyDll.GetType("MyDll.MyClass");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(MyLoadClass);
```